# DFSR File Filters on Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dfs-r

I've got a serverfarm which utilizes DFSR for file and folder replication.  I'm familiar with File and Folder Filters on the replicated folders for the group.  I'm curious if these can be set per server?  I basically need to exclude robots.txt to and from 1 server but I need it to replicate through the rest of the members.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. The files in the RF are replicated to all members.